# What is the use of .then() in async function call? it seems to do nothing and never called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, promise

I have an `async` `axios` request:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Function : Get > User > Current Avatar
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    async function getUserCurrentAvatar() {

        // Ajax URL
        const ajax_url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_API_ROOT + 'user' + '/' + session.user.id + '/' + 'edit/avatar/getusercurrentavatar';

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | AJAX > Request
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        await axios.post(ajax_url)
            .then(response => {

                setCurrentUserAvatarId(response.data.id);
                setCurrentUserAvatarUrl(response.data.current_avatar);

            }).catch((error) => {

                // Error
                if (error.response) {
                    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                    // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                    // console.log(error.response.data);
                    // console.log(error.response.status);
                    // console.log(error.response.headers);

                } else if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the
                    // browser and an instance of
                    // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                    console.log(error.request);

                } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                }
                console.log(error.config);

            });

    }
```

and I called it in `useEffect()` like:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Use Effect 1
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    useEffect(() => {

        // Session > Available
        if(session) {
            getUserCurrentAvatar();
        }

    }, [session]);
```

but I am getting the warning `Promise returned from getUserCurrentAvatar is ignored, Add '.then()'`

my question is can I do side effects inside `.then()`?

Inside `async function getUserCurrentAvatar() { ... }` I set the `state` for:

```
                setCurrentUserAvatarId(response.data.id);
                setCurrentUserAvatarUrl(response.data.current_avatar);
```

I need to perform a `sideEffect` after `currentUserAvatarUrl` state is set, I tried in `useEffect()` with `then()` but it does not work:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Use Effect 1
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    useEffect(() => {

        // Session > Available
        if(session) {
            getUserCurrentAvatar().then(() => {

                const fileName = 'myFile.jpg'
                imageSrcToFile(currentUserAvatarUrl, fileName).then();
                
            });
        }

    }, [session]);
```

the anonymous function in `then()` was never triggered, nothing in it works

but if I do it in another `useEffect()` as usual it works:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Use Effect 2
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    useEffect(() => {

        const fileName = 'myFile.jpg'
        imageSrcToFile(currentUserAvatarUrl, fileName).then();

    }, [currentUserAvatarUrl]);
```

What is the use of `then()` then?
Why the IDE is giving me warning everytime to include `then()` after the `async` function call?

**EDIT**: I tried:

```
    useEffect(() => {

        // Session > Available
        if(session) {
            getUserCurrentAvatar().then((response) => {

                alert(`Received response: ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);

                const fileName = 'myFile.jpg'
                imageSrcToFile(currentUserAvatarUrl, fileName).then();

            });
        }

    }, [session]);
```

but the `response` I got is `Received response: undefined`

Comment: After executing the asynchronous function, the promise instance is fetched with status not pending like fulfilled. So depending on your purpose.

Comment: can you clarify more? do you meant the code in `.then()` is only executed if the status is `not pending` or `not fulfilled`?

Answer (score 0):

`Async` function does not return value directly it returns the `promise` and therefore requires `then`, you can use `async-await` and vice-versa.

The issue with the code, getting the response `undefined` since `getUserCurrentAvatar()` does not return anything. I have updated code as below.

```
function getUserCurrentAvatar() {
  // Ajax URL
  const ajax_url =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_API_ROOT +
    "user" +
    "/" +
    session.user.id +
    "/" +
    "edit/avatar/getusercurrentavatar";

  /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | AJAX > Request
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
  return axios
    .post(ajax_url)
    .then((response) => {
      //no need to set values on here first return, then set values on last promise
      // setCurrentUserAvatarId(response.data.id);
      // setCurrentUserAvatarUrl(response.data.current_avatar);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        console.log("Error", error.message);
      }
      console.log(error.config);
    });
}
```

Now, you will able to get a response and then use that response data for your subsequent request as below. In addition, if you are using `then` avoid using `async` `await` or vice-versa.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Session > Available
  if (session) {
    getUserCurrentAvatar().then((response) => {
      alert(`Received response: ${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);

      const fileName = "myFile.jpg";
      imageSrcToFile(response.current_avatar, fileName).then();
    });
  }
}, [session]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tweak your code as below

1. Inside async function getUserCurrentAvatar -> return await axios.post(ajax_url) and dont add handler there.
2. Inside UseEffect call the async function and add handler.
3. setCurrentUserAvatarUrl(response.data.current_avatar,()=>{
   //Add your code here that will run after state value is set
   });